# Can XPointer "follow" links?

Tags: xml, xpath, fragment-identifier, xpointer

I know I can specify a node another document using XPointer:

```
http://www.google.com/#xpointer(...)
```

But, can I specify an a/@href node in the current document, and point to a node in that document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this to go to the root node first, then back down to the hyperlink:

```
#xpointer(here()//ancestor::*[1]/ancestor::*[1]/descendant::a[@id='#1'])
```